# The link produced by a custom formatter only shows its text when moused over

Tags: grails, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid grails plugin.

Column model for the column is:

```
  {name:'id', index:'id', editable:true, align:'center', formatter:jobListLinkFormatter}
```

Custom formatter is:

```
 function jobListLinkFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){


    var url = "${createLink(action:'jobListJSON')}" +"/"+cellvalue;

    var link ="<a href='" + url + "'"+">my link</a>";
    return link;
  };
```

The link is produced correctly, however the text 'my link' only shows when moused over. What is the cause of this problem?

Add generate html: The text for the link only shows when mouse over on the row and 'ui-state-hover' is applied

```
<table id="configGrid" class="jqTable ui-jqgrid-btable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_configGrid" style="width: 1178px; ">
   <tbody>
       <tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height:auto">
         <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:1178px;"></td>
       </tr>
        <tr id="4" role="row" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
          <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="my link" aria-describedby="configGrid_id">
              <a href="/icm.server/configuration/jobListJSON/5">my link</a>
          </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post the result html?

Comment: I suppose your problm is not in the part which you posted. The comment of Hoàng Long is correct. Moreover the first part of `urs` (the `"${createLink(action:'jobListJSON')}" +"/"`) can be set outside of the formatter. If you include in your question the URL or the full test code which can be used to reproduce your problem one can easy help you to find and to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try adding in your link

```
function jobListLinkFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){


    var url = "${createLink(action:'jobListJSON')}" +"/"+cellvalue;

    var link ="<a href='" + url + "'"+" style='font-color:red' >my link</a>";
    return link;
  };
```

or class="ui-state-error-text"

if this will work that means that you have problems with css so in firebug inspect your link and see what styles are applied to this link and your font color is the same as background or font size is tiny or something like that.